# Right align menu sub elements with css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I don't know how to do with css in order to my sub elements would be in right side. Can someone help?

```css
.navbar-collapse {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#top">1</a></li>
      <li><a class="drop" href="#">2</a>
               <ul>
                          <li><a href="#about">22</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#portfolio">222</a></li>
         </ul>  
         </li>
      <li><a href="#service">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#team">4</a></li>
      <li><a class="drop" href="#">5</a>
      <ul>
                          <li><a href="#about2">55?</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#team2">555</a></li>
         </ul>  
         </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">6</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Now my sub element(22,222 and 55,555) are at the bottom(Check out in Full page).

Answer (score 0):

The thin is that `ul` sub element(22,222 and 55,555) and `a.drop` have`display: block` just replace it by display: inline-block` like this:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
  .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

  .sub-menu,
  .nav>li>a{
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  .sub-menu{
    padding-left: 20px;    
  }
</style>
  


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#top">1</a></li>
        
        <li><a class="drop" href="#">2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#about">22</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">222</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li><a href="#service">3</a></li>
        
        <li><a href="#team">4</a></li>
        
        <li><a class="drop" href="#">5</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#about2">55?</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#team2">555</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li><a href="#contact">6</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

See it in full page because `.navbar-collapse` has `display: none` bellow 768px;

[Here working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/L0jLy308/)

If you want the `ul` in right side just the overrite the bootstrap styles for that element like this:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
  
  .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 400px;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

  .sub-menu,
  .nav>li>a{
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  .sub-menu{
    padding-left: 20px;    
  }
  
  
  /*overwrite the default styles of bootstrat bellow 768px*/
  .navbar-nav{
    float: right !important;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .navbar-nav>li{
    float: left;
  }
  
</style>
  

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#top">1</a></li>
        
        <li><a class="drop" href="#">2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#about">22</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">222</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li><a href="#service">3</a></li>
        
        <li><a href="#team">4</a></li>
        
        <li><a class="drop" href="#">5</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#about2">55?</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#team2">555</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li><a href="#contact">6</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Here the jsfiddle for the above](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/s99ho0qz/)

Comment: OK, but I want to what sub menu elements would be in right side in 768 media quires, in other cases i have css and its working well

Comment: @Barbara I update the answer to maintain the sub menu in right side bellow 768px, let me know if now works for you.

Comment: @ Yandy_Viera Thank you! Its almost good, but when I click in 2,when sub menu 22 and 222 are too low , can't see them .

Comment: @Barbara how can I see that behavior, in the example of your question I can't see what you said, can you add more details or an example where I can test it?